# MS SQL fulltext search with ignoring special characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a following (simplified) database structure:
[places]

- name NVARCHAR(255)
- description TEXT (usually quite a lot of text)
- region_id INT FK

[regions]

- id INT PK
- name NVARCHAR(255)

[regions_translations]

- lang_code NVARCHAR(5) FK
- label NVARCHAR(255)
- region_id INT FK

In real db I have few more fields in [places] table to search in, and [countries] table with similar structure to [regions].

My requirements are:

1. Search using name, description and region label, using the same behaviour as `name LIKE '%text%' OR description LIKE '%text5' OR regions_translations.label LIKE '%text%'`
2. Ignore all special characters like Ą, Ć, Ó, Š, Ö, Ü, etc. so for example, when someone search for
   `PO ZVAIGZDEM` I return a place with name `PO ŽVAIGŽDĖM` - but of course also return this record, when user uses proper characters with accents.
3. Quite fast. ;)

I had a few approaches to solve this issue.

1. Create new column 'searchable_content', normalize text (so replace Ą -> A, Ö -> O and so on) and just do simple `SELECT ... FROM places WHERE searchable_content LIKE '%text%'` but it was slow
2. Add fulltext search index to table `places` and `regions_translations` - it was faster, but I could not find a way to ignore special characters (characters are from various of languages, so specyfying index language will not work)
3. Create new column as in first attempt, and addfulltext index only on that column - it was faster then attempt 1 (probably because I do not need to join tables) and I could manually normalize the content, but I feel like it's not a great solution.

Question is - what is the best approach here?
My top priority is to ignore special characters.

EDIT:
`ALTER FULLTEXT CATALOG [catalog_name] REBUILD WITH ACCENT_SENSITIVITY = OFF`
Probably is a solution to my issue with special characters (need to test it a bit more) - I query too fast, and index did not rebuild, that's why I did not get any records.

Comment: FYI, the `text` data type has been deprecated since **2005**; you should really have switch to `varchar(MAX)` by now.

Comment: I did not know about that, thank You - I have checked that, and we have `NVARCHAR(max)` id database, my fault, when thinking about link strings in sql. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `COLLATE` clause on a column to specify a sql collation that will treat these special characters as their non-accented counterparts. Think of it as essentially casting one data type as another, except you're casting `é` as `e` (for example). You can use the same tool to return case sensitive or case insensitive results.

The documentation talks a little more about it, and you can do a search to find exactly which collation works best for you.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collations?view=sql-server-ver16